# Windows 7 : soft RAID1 and dynamic volumes reliability

Tags: windows-7, software-raid, raid-1, dynamic-disk

My setup is quite classic nowadays : 
1 SSD for system/apps and 2 HDDs for data setup in a fake RAID1 array.

I also have a backup scheduled every week for the data drive in case it fails because I don't trust RAID1 for that purpose, and that's not the goal of RAID1 anyway ...

My RAID1 is only there in case of a drive hardware faillure, so I don't loose the changes since the last backup.

Now I'm not very happy with my fake raid. It slows down boot time a lot, apparently it removes the TRIM support for my SSD and I've been said it's not reliable.

Therefore, what I was thinking is to do a software raid 1 using Windows 7 dynamic volumes.

Now, to do that, I have to upgrade to win 7 professional (I have "home" now) so I'm wondering if it's worth it.

Does anyone have exerience with dynamic volumes ?

- Do they really work ?
- If one drive fails, will I be able to update my backup, replace the drive and continue as if nothing had happened ?
- Do they cause headaches when doing hdd maintenance ? (defrag for instance ?)
- Are they seen as regular drives by other tools ? (like recuva, defraggler, and so on ... ?)

Best regards

Comment: Well I finally did it and everything seems to be ok. I don't know about faillure recovery, but the rest works perfectly.